# Upload Video Clip On CKEditor5 Using SimpleUpload?

Tags: file-upload, phoenix-framework, ckeditor5

I have tried to upload mp4 format videos in a online-built ckeditor5 by trying to modify the editor configuration like this:

```
ClassicEditor.Editor
        .create( document.querySelector( '#editor' ),
        {      
                image: {
                    imageUploadConfig: {
                        types: [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg', 'mp4' ]
                    }, ...
```

but it doesn't work. The mp4 files do not appear in the supported types when browsing and choosing them from all types does not have any effect. What am I doing wrong and is there another way to do this?

Comment: https://github.com/Technologie-Visao/ckeditor5-video